# How to solve such integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

i am trying to solve the following integration but not reaching the final step as the integration results in infinity. $\int_0^\infty y^{2m+1}e^{-C_{2}(x+\rho)y}\text{d}y$. Where $m,C_2,x$ and $\rho$ are constants. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the definition of Gamma  function.

Comment: Ok .....got it....but final expression is not exactly in terms of definition of gamma function....

Comment: If you make the substitution $t=C_2(x+\rho) y$ you will get it in terms of Gamma function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To flesh out Kavi's hint, assuming that $C_2(x + \rho)$ is positive (if it's negative, the integral doesn't converge) we can make the substitution $t = C_2(x + \rho)y$ gives $dy = \frac{1}{C_2(x + \rho)} dt$ and the integral becomes
$$\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{t}{C_2(x + \rho)}\right)^{2m + 1} e^{-t} \left(\frac{1}{C_2(x + \rho)}dt\right) = \left(\frac{1}{C_2(x + \rho)}\right)^{2 m + 2} \Gamma(2m + 2)$$
(In your final answer, you might want to remember that $\Gamma(2m + 2) = (2m + 1)!$)

Comment: Got it entirely ......@Kavi ,@ Paulinho